# Time complexity of this function O(n^2logn)?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I'm trying to figure the time complexity of this function out:
Pseudo-code

```
def inc(m):
  if m>12:
     return;
  for i in range(1,m):
     //some code
  mergeSort(array,0,n-1)
  for j in range(1,m):
     //some code
  inc(m+=1);
```

Is the time complexity O(n^2logN)? as you can see, this example is of a recursive function calling a differente recursive function for sorting and at the end itself. I don't know if the for loops affect and also the calling of another recursive function as merge sort.

Comment: The `if m>12` has a huge impact on the running time... most of this is going to reduce to constant time, it really depends on the implementation of merge sort.

Comment: @user700390 the merge sort in this case is the average case, O(nlogn). But overall, do you mean that the complexity of the function could be O(1)?

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity of this code is O(m*n logn), since m is constant which is no more than 12, we can say the complexity is bounded by the complexity of merge sort which is O(nlogn). At each recursive call, the function performs two loops, one before the merge sort  and another after it and they both have complexity of O(m). The merge sort has a time complexity of O(nlog n).

Therefore, the total time complexity would be m * (2m + n * log n) which is O(m * (m + n * log n))= O(m^2) + O(mnlogn)